# Can we achieve Algolia like functionality from elastic search ?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine, algolia

I want to implement contextual search in my web application for that I adopted algolia search and its working fine and i loved the functionality.

But its too much costly  so is there any alternative for that which is less costly.

Is elastic search a Good option for that ? is it possible to achieve same functionality from elastic search?

Can we do contextual searching from elastic search ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "contextual search"?

Comment: @OlivierLance 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contextual_searching

basically i want to get ans sort results based on typo mistakes and no of occurrence etc.